# Break the string (udacity: Intro to python )

Tags: python

> Write a loop with a break statement to create a string, news_ticker, that is exactly 140 characters long. You should create the news ticker by adding headlines from the headlines list, inserting a space in between each headline. If necessary, truncate the last headline in the middle so that news_ticker is exactly 140 characters long.

> headlines = ["Local Bear Eaten by Man",
> "Legislature Announces New Laws",
> "Peasant Discovers Violence Inherent in System",
> "Cat Rescues Fireman Stuck in Tree",
> "Brave Knight Runs Away",
> "Papperbok Review: Totally Triffic"]

My solution:

```
headlines = ["Local Bear Eaten by Man",
             "Legislature Announces New Laws",
             "Peasant Discovers Violence Inherent in System",
             "Cat Rescues Fireman Stuck in Tree",
             "Brave Knight Runs Away",
             "Papperbok Review: Totally Triffic"]

news_ticker = ""
# write your loop here
for news in headlines:
    news_ticker += news + " "
    if len(news_ticker) >= 140:
        break


while len(news_ticker) > 140:
    news_ticker.replace(news_ticker[-1] , "")

    

print(news_ticker)
```

This code is taking forever to run. I used 'print' statements to know the cause of this error and found that the problem is with the 'while' loop but I can't figure out anything else.

PS: My english is not good, so pardon any grammatical mistakes.

Comment: you replace the string, but never assign it back to news ticker so the length never changes

Comment: Try this with two nested `for` loops instead of these two successive for and while. Also, keep in mind that string are also iterable: `for char in my_string:`. This should help you to resolve your exercise

Comment: You could also just skip the endless while loop and just use `news_ticker = news_ticker[:140]`

Comment: Also, `replace` does not absolutely do what you are using it for. `"abcacd".replace("a", "3") == "3bc3cd"`, without changing the original string.